# iOS Safari sharing image URL as string instead of image

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, blob, share

I'm currently creating an AR web app that allows you to take a screenshot, converts from base64 to a blob file and shows a preview on screen. When shared from chrome it sends the image fine using `navigator.share()`, but when shared from safari (long tap image and hit share) it instead shares the blob url (`blob:https://`) as a string. It appears with a 'save to photos' option as well so seems to know it's an image. Is there any way to force it to share the image instead of the url (`image.src`)?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue! I tried using both data URL and blob URLs and either way, Safari tries to share the local-only URL rather than the actual image data. Did you end up finding a workaround?

Comment: same problem, can't fix :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was able to fix by rendering the image to the Canvas and then calling `toDataURL()` to get the base64 encoding. If you use this as your image source - rather than a Blob - people can just long press on the image and use the native share functionality, without any issue.